# VS Code file .vscode/extensions.json select custom version of one extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this code in .vscode/extensions.json

```
{
  "recommendations": [
    johnpapa.Angular2
  ]
}
```

but I don't want to install the *latest* version of johnpapa.Angular2 (currently version 17) I want to install version 11.

How can I write this custom version in .vscode/extensions.json file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. It's not supported. And it was raised before as a feature-request and it was deemed out of scope. See [Allow specifying a version for workspace recommended extensions #138048](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138048).

But FYI- once you've installed an extension, you can [roll back to an older version](/q/42626065/11107541) and [disable automatic updates for that particular extension](/q/51965933/11107541).

Comment: Please click on the feature-request and upvote it. 

Now I must commit a file listing the extensions versions to make vscode work in my project :-(